# How to transfer ETH while updating a struct

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, ether

While I am in my first steps on solidity development, I am solving a sale exercise. The goal, among other things, is to post an item in a struct and then someone to be able to buy it. I am struggling to find a way to call a function (via using only the item ID) and then transfer the listed ETH to the seller.

Here is the code:

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;
contract sales{

    struct Items{
        uint256 productID;
        string productname;
        address productOwner;
    }


    struct ItemsForSale{
        //uint256 forSaleID; more efficient for have one ID
        uint256 productID; 
        uint256 productPrice;

    }

    struct Offers{
        uint256 offerID;
        uint256 productID;
        uint256 offerPrice;

    } 

    uint numItems;
    uint numsaleItems;
    mapping(uint => Items) public item;
    mapping(uint => ItemsForSale) public sales;

    constructor(){
        
    }

    function createItem(string memory _productName) public returns (string memory, uint productID){
        productID = numItems++;
        Items storage _item = item[productID]; 
        _item.productID = productID;
        _item.productname = _productName;
        _item.productOwner = msg.sender;
        return ( "Your Item is listed with the Id:" , productID);
        }

    function listItemForSale(uint256 _productID, uint256 _productPrice) public{
        sales[_productID] = ItemsForSale(_productID,_productPrice);
    }

    function buyItem(uint _forSaleID) public payable{
        Items storage _itembought = item[_forSaleID];
        _itembought.productOwner = msg.sender; 
        //PLUS HERE I WANT TO BE ABLE TO SEND THE ETH AMOUNT FOUND IN THE ItemsForSale 
        //STRUCT FROM THE CALLER OF THIS FUNCTION TO THE OWNER OF THE ITEM (found in the 
        //Items struct)

    }
}
```

Thank you all in advance :)

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
    function buyItem(uint _forSaleID) public payable{
        Items storage _itembought = item[_forSaleID];
        ItemsForSale memory _itemSale = sales[_forSaleID];
        require(_itemSale.productPrice == msg.value, "Product costs more");
        payable(_itembought.productOwner).transfer(_itemSale.productPrice);

        _itembought.productOwner = msg.sender;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @matank001 ! Question: I always get the "Product costs more" exception even though I have 100 test eth in the wallet i call this function and i set up the productPrice == 1 in the setter function. Why is that?

Comment: msg.value is in wei not eth, set productPrice to be 1 ether not just one.

Comment: thank you once again, I input the price into the struct as eth like this :
```
    function listItemForSale(uint256 _productID, uint256 _productPrice) public {
        sales[numSales] = ItemsForSale(numSales,_productID,_productPrice*1 ether);
        numSales++;
    }
```
Still no luck :/